# Choose/Avoid Symfony Forms

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I am using Symfony.
I am exploring Symfony Forms  and exploring its benifit and drawback.
I guess the main use of using these forms is the validation part.

But I need to change the html provided to me as per syntax of symfony.

Can anyone suggest me drawbacks of using them considering I wont upgrade from symfony1.4 to symfony2.0 in near future.

Some points I can think of are:

1. We are not able to integrate new html changes.
2. changes in html need to be done

Comment: You don't have to use the form widgets to use symfony forms, it's fine to just use the validators. The only drawback will be that you need to manually hydrate the fields yourself.

Comment: Since you are not able to move to newer version of symfony.
Any new html update cant be easily integrated into forms